# error with devise in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

So, I have never used devise before and am trying to implement it in my program via http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise.  I installed it and everything word for word as this guy did and then when I try and go to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up, I get this error:

```
 Routing Error

 No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_up"
```

here is what I get when I do rake route:

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)              {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
    user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
 destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)             {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
        password POST   /users/password(.:format)             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
    new_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
   edit_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)        {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                 PUT    /users/password(.:format)             {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                 POST   /users/registration(.:format)         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
             new GET    /users/registration/sign_up(.:format) {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
            edit GET    /users/registration/edit(.:format)    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                 PUT    /users/registration(.:format)         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                 DELETE /users/registration(.:format)         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
       vote_post POST   /posts/:id/vote(.:format)             {:action=>"vote", :controller=>"posts"}
           posts GET    /posts(.:format)                      {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts"}
                 POST   /posts(.:format)                      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts"}
        new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"posts"}
       edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)             {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}
            post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"}
                 PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"posts"}
                 DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
            root        /                                     {:controller=>"users", :action=>"index"}
```

If you watch the video the guy is just able to go to that web address and it just works.  I noticed that there is a [GET] /users/registration/sign_up(.:format) but no [GET] /users/sign_up like the guy in the video has. Is there something I am missing?

p.s.

this is the error I get when I try to go to one of the routes listed above (user/sign_in):

```
 NoMethodError in Devise/registrations#new
 Showing /Users/davidfleischhauer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise- 1.1.rc0/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:

 undefined method `user_registration_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f85eafec758>:0x007f85eaf77ed0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind the video is a year+ old :)

If you look at the [current devise source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb) where the routes are generated you'll see that it apparently no longer creates a "sign_up" route--looks like the registration paths are the current method.

It also looks like you're using a release candidate version, which always makes me a little nervous, since that's a release *candidate* and not necessarily 100% stable--which might explain why the default template is using a path variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: I knew the video was 1+ years old but I figured if I used the same version of devise he used, it should work exactly the same?  now I know he was using rails 3 beta 2.  I dont know if that would change anything since I am using the current version.  There is a GET and a POST path for users/sign_in so shouldnt I be able to go to users/sign_in on my browser and it would show a view?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use new_user_registration_path in order to create a link to the sign up page. You have to use new_user_session_path in order to create a link to sign_in.

Comment: I tried using the method 'new_user_registration_path' to go to the sign up page and I get this error:  undefined local variable or method `new_user_registration_path'

Comment: <%= link_to "New User", new_user_registration_path %>

Comment: Hmm that looks fine. When I run rake routes my display shows          new_user_registration GET        /users/sign_up(.:format) instead of what yours shows

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to figure out why you are using Devise version 1.1rc0 and not the latest gem available which is 1.4.7? I have several applications all running this latest version in which the `sign_up` path works just fine. I would recommend updating to the latest version of the gem and try again. Outside of that, I can only think of problems that could be caused by something in your `routes.rb` file or if you are trying to override the Devise Registrations Controller.

Answer (score 0):

add to routes.rb this is:

```
devise_for :users do

  get'users/sign_out'=>'devise/sessions#destroy'

end
```

it's for sign_out

for sign_up go to `config/initializers/secret_token.rb` and copy line: `config.secret_token ='...'`
and paste it in config/aplication.rb